# My storage was not updated

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, upgrade, storage

I just changed my storage plan for 50 GB for $0.99 per month. When i went on settings>General>Storage and icloud usage, where it said storage above it i didnt have more storage. But the second box, where it said icloud abov it had upgraded to 50 GB. But i dont have any more storage for me to be able to get more apps etc.

Answer (score 8):

Your iCloud **storage** is how much data you can keep online, in the cloud.
This is **variable**, depending on how much you pay, for what you need. Your first 5GB is free.

The iPhone itself has a **fixed** hardware **memory**, or space, which can only be chosen when you buy it, in 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, or 256 GB configurations.
The total you see in Settings > General > Storage will never be quite this figure, as some of that is needed for the formatting of the memory & the data structure itself.
This memory is where it stores all apps, music, documents etc that your phone can use.

[image]