# iCloud Storage - No photos or videos but still shows as full

Tags: icloud, storage

I have iPhone 6....and standard iCloud storage of 5GB. Please see pictures - I have absolutely no pictures and videos on my iPhone but still the iCloud storage says I have more than 1 GB of photos on my iCloud. When I log into my iCloud storage via PC, it shows there are no photos or videos (Moments and Albums are all blanks).iPhone Screenshot

I keep getting annoying messages that my iCloud storage is full....when I go to delete the pictures and videos, there are no such files. EXTREMELY ANNOYING. Please please help how to delete the "non-existent" photos and videos from the iCloud.

[pc screenshot
[image: ][1]]

Comment: It may be possible that these pictures are still in your 'Recently Deleted' album on your iPhone. Is there?

Comment: Does this thread help explain what you might want to do? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217065/my-storage-was-not-updated

Answer (score 1):

Go into the iCloud Photo Library submenu (from screenshot above) and select "Disable and Delete" to turn off iCloud Photo Library. Delete everything in your Photos app - don't forget to check shared photos and all albums. Then re-enable iCloud Photo Library.

iMessages also takes up space - clear out/delete old messages (the attachment images may be counted toward your photo allotment). May help, may not, but worth a shot.