# iCloud storage.

Tags: icloud, storage

What are the benefits of buying iCloud storage ? What's the point? What is it for? I bought some and I unfortunately thought it would give me more space for apps or photos but it still says I don't have storage so I guess not I just like to know what's the point of it what is it used for and if there are any other ways to free up space without deleting stuff.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217065/my-storage-was-not-updated/217071#217071

Answer (score 0):

Apple's iCloud is just like any other cloud. It allows you store files, documents, pictures, etc.
You get 5GB free iCloud storage with Apple devices.