# iPhone and iCloud storage not fill but isn't allowing me to take a picture

Tags: ios, icloud, photos, video, storage

i have an ihphone X with 64GB of storage and 200GB of icloud storage. as you can see bellow both of them have still available space.

[image: Storage]

Unfortunatelytely the "iPhone storage full, can't take a picture" notification still pops up. i tried workig something out via mac but nothing changed, also my iCloud storage says it's at 1% deespite the fact it has 114GB left... Can someone help?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/217071/85275

Comment: See https://appletoolbox.com/2017/08/taking-photo-iphone-says-storage-full/

Answer (score 1):

That is iCloud online storage and not the actual device storage.

See [My storage was not updated](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217065/my-storage-was-not-updated/)

You need the storage on the device to take a photo. Check it in Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage.

> The iPhone itself has a fixed hardware memory, or space, which can only be chosen when you buy it, in 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, or 256 GB configurations.
>   The total you see in Settings > General > Storage will never be quite this figure, as some of that is needed for the formatting of the memory & the data structure itself.
>   This memory is where it stores all apps, music, documents etc that your phone can use.
>
> [image]